# Showdialog error for fivem projector script

Tags: showdialog, fivem, projector, esx

`Can anyone help me figure out why this script is not working? I bought the A5 projector script and been getting this error:

client/cl_projector.lua:122: attempt to call a nil value (global 'showDialog")

And here is the line in question:

```
local options = {
{
icon = "fa-solid fa-play",
label = 'Start/Change Projector',
onSelect = function(data)
showDialog('ProjectorInput', 'Enter Url Here', 'WWW.GOOGLE.COM', '','SubmitUrl', function() end, true)
end,
},
```

I’ve tried asking the dev but their support is non existent, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

I’ve changed the framework, looked for resources online, tried contacting the script developers`